# "Variable expected" error when updating a lamda value

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

I'm getting an error at this line ->

```
selectedScreen() = navItem
```

Here's the complete function:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun ScaffoldView(
    isScaffold: ()-> Boolean, selectedScreen: () -> NavItem
){

    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                title = {
                    when(selectedScreen().route){
                        
                    }
                },
                colors = TopAppBarDefaults.smallTopAppBarColors(
                    containerColor = Color.LightGray
                )
            )
        },
        bottomBar = {
            NavigationBar(
                modifier = Modifier.height(50.dp),
                containerColor = Color.White
            ) {
                listOfNavItems.forEach{navItem ->
                    NavigationBarItem(
                        icon = {
                            Icon(imageVector = navItem.icon, contentDescription = null)
                        },
                        selected = navItem == selectedScreen(),
                        onClick = {
                             selectedScreen() = navItem
                        },
                        colors = NavigationBarItemDefaults.colors(
                            selectedIconColor = Color.White,
                            indicatorColor = Color.Black
                        )
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    ) {paddingValues ->
        Box(modifier = Modifier.padding(paddingValues)){

        }
    }
}
```

And here's how I'm calling the function:

```
ScaffoldView(
            isScaffold = {isScaffold.value},
            selectedScreen = {selectedScreen}
        )
```

Is it possible to update lambda value just like mutable val?

Also, just in case you are wondering why I'm using lambda instead of mutable val, that's because I saw google recommend that lambdas are more performant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `selectedScreen` is a lambda that takes no arguments and returns a `NavItem`, its value can not be changed from the `ScaffoldView`. If you want to set `navItem` in it's `onClick`, you have to add another function param to your composable:

```
fun ScaffoldView(
    isScaffold: () -> Boolean,
    selectedScreen: () -> NavItem,
    selectScreen: (NavItem) -> Unit,
){
```

And then call it

```
                        onClick = {
                             selectScreen(navItem)
                        }
```

And implement it in the parent composable

```
    ScaffoldView(
        isScaffold = { isScaffold.value },
        selectedScreen = { selectedScreen },
        selectScreen = { navItem ->
            selectedScreen = navItem
        }
    )
```

Comment: I tried what you said. And there's no error now. But its not working. I mean, the bottom navigation is not happening when i click on the icons.

Here's how i'm calling the funtion. I'm not sure if its correct:

ScaffoldView(
            isScaffold = {isScaffold.value},
            selectedScreen = {selectedScreen},
            selectScreen = {navItem -> selectedScreen}
        )

Comment: @Raj Your `selectedScreen` must be a `State` and you update it like `selectScreen = { navItem -> selectedScreen = navItem }`